# Мультизагрузка файлов с progress bar

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, fileupload

Мучает вопрос, как грамотно реализовать множественную загрузку файлов, чтобы при загрузке у каждого файла был свой progress bar.
Делал по примеру из статьи https://habr.com/post/109079
Изначально в инпут выбираем нужные файлы, затем при нажатии кнопки "загрузить", js прогоняет объект FileList на наличие выбранных в инпуте файлов и для каждого из них делает ajax запрос с отображением состояния файла, а на выходе сервер (испольую PHP) обрабатывает каждый файл по одному. Насколько эта реализация оправдана и есть ли другие способы реализовать подобное? (без использования сторонних плагинов).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#file-input').on('change', function(){
    var files = $(this).prop('files');
    $('#file-container').empty();
    for(var file of files)
    {
    //создаем превью из названия файла и програсс бара
      var elem = $('<div class="file-previev"><p>'+file.name+'</p><progress class="file-progress" value="0" max="100"></progress></div>').appendTo($('#file-container'));
      //добавляем к контейнеру с превью свойство файла для передачи
      elem.get(0).fileInfo = file;
    }
  });
  $('#start').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#file-container').find('.file-preview').each(function(){
      var file = this.file;
      var progress = $(this).find('.file-progress');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: file,
        xhr: function(){
          var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
          xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt){
            var percent = Math.ceil(evt.loaded/evt.total);
            $(progress).attr('value', percent);
          }
        },
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-upload" method="post">
  <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple="true"/>
  <button id="start" type="submit">Загрузить</button>
</form>
<div id="file-container"></div>
```

Собственно все подобные решения, которые я видел всегда подразумевают то, что на каждый файл посылается отдельный ajax запрос, который обрабатывает файл. Смущает этот момент, поскольку без реализации progress bar, просто собирают массив из инпут с именем file[] и в php работают с массивом файлов. А также не совсем понятно, как именно тут с помощью ajax передать файл в PHP и правильно его обработать, ибо видел разные реализации как в этом коде, так и с использованием объекта FormData.

Comment: Код - лучше тысячи слов!) Покажите, какие у вас наработки есть сейчас.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, дополнил к вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дошел до истины, как можно грамотно сделать мультизагрузку с прогресс баром:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $('#file-input');
  var button = $('#file-submit');
  var container = $('#file-container');
  input.on('change', function() {
    var files = $(this).prop('files');
    for (var file of files) {
      var elem = $('<div class="file-info"><p>' + file.name + '</p><progress class="progress-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress></div>').appendTo(container);
      //добавляем инфу о файле в свойство превью
      elem.get(0).file = file;
    }
  });
  //асинхронный колбек закачки файлов
  button.on('click', async function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    //пускаем закачку каждого файла параллельно с помощью Promise.all и дожидаемся закачки всех файлов с помощью await.
    await Promise.all($('.file-info').map(upload));
    console.log('готово');
  });

  //асинхронная функция закачки файла
  async function upload(index, elem) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', elem.file);
    var progress = $(elem).find('.progress-bar');
    //ждем ответа об успешной обработке файла на стороне сервера
    const res = await $.ajax({
      url: '/',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: data,
      type: 'post',
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt) {
          var percent = Math.ceil(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);
          progress.attr('value', percent);
        }
        return xhr;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="file-form" method="post">
  <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple>
  <button id="file-submit" type="button">Отправить</button><br/>
  <div id="file-container"></div>
</form>
```

Примерно так я сделал решение с мультизагрузкой для себя. Разумеется этот код не идеален и его можно доработать проверками на тип, размер, отмену закачки и т.д.