# Помогите решить задачу c мультизагрузкой файлов с progress bar

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать эту конструкцию на javascript?

```
var elem = $('<div class="file-info"><p>' + file.name + '</p><progress class="progress-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress></div>').appendTo(container);
      //добавляем инфу о файле в свойство превью
      elem.get(0).file = file;
```

Дело в том что я пытаюсь [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873957/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-progress-bar) решение автора сделать на чистом js, но этот кусок у меня не получается сделать правильно. У меня в моем варианте каждый раз значение файла перезаписывается на последний из загруженных файлов.
Вот мой код:

```
container.innerHTML = "<div class="file-info"><p>' + file.name + '</p><progress class="progress-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress></div>"+container.innerHTML;
container.querySelectorAll(".file-info")[0].file = file;
```

Comment: Прочитайте про `FileReader`. В нем есть замечательное событие `onprogress`, прочитайте и о нем тоже.

Comment: Меня интересует не как сделать прогресс бар, а именно как сделать те пару строчек на js в контексте той функции из решения, ссылку на которое я указал. Самое интересное что только этот кусочек кода у меня не получался, но я уже нашел решение сам.

Answer (score -1):

Я нашел альтернативное решение вопроса.

```js
    var container = document.getElementById("file-container");//Это чтобы понятнее
    container.file = {};//Объявляем объект

    //......//здесь идет код

    if(container.file.hasOwnProperty(id_name[0]) == false){//Это все вместо тех 2х строчек

        container.innerHTML = '<div class="file-info"><p>' + file.name + '</p><progress class="progress-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress></div>'+container.innerHTML;

        container.file[id_name[0]] = file;
    }//Дальше в функции где идет отправка нужно сделать перебор объекта и готово
```